# scipy.stats.gaussian_kde: TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature

Tags: python, scipy, kernel-density

When I tried to calculate gaussian kernel using function `gaussian_kde`, I got an error: `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add`.
Data I used is numpy.array:

```py
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

data = np.array([0.056004922086, -0.067110140912, 0.047649429128, 0.013352490798, 0.056957475051,
0.064815486825, 0.042257559312, 0.049155256114, -0.002745214579, -0.034729529946,
-0.0087654892625, 0.001477248489, 0.089200991785, 0.061195174967, 0.015295170704,
0.00080743905519, 0.048158569509, 0.034026643059, 0.037892055914, 0.017979245009], dtype=object)

gaussian_kde(data)
```

Comment: Note the `dtype` of your array: `dtype=object`.  Most of the scipy functions do not handle object arrays.  Convert it to an array of floats first, e.g. `gaussian_kde(data.astype(float))`

Comment: @Warren Weckesser, Thanks! I just found that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/d43f5t/no_loop_matching_the_specified_signature_and/). The data type in the array I used above is object, but `gaussian_kde` needs float type as input array. So it should be converted to float type.

```py
gaussian_kde(data.astype(np.float64))
```